# apply jquery to only clicked elements children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a very simple script to toggle a div and it works fine. The problem is that because of the selectors I'm using, if I have more of the items I'm applying the script to all of them respond to a click on any of them. What I'd like to achive is so when I click on one button only it's text appears and the others doesn't.

```js
$('.wrapper-button').click(function(){
 $('.wrapper p').toggle();
});
```

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.wrapper-text{
  
  background-color:salmon;
}

.wrapper-button{
  background-color:darkred;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
<div class='wrapper-button' id="btn-1">
  Click me
</div>
<p class='wrapper-text' id="txt-1">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
</div>

<div class='wrapper'>
<div class='wrapper-button' id="btn-2">
  Click me
</div>
<p class='wrapper-text' id="txt-2">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
</div>
```

I was wondering maybe I could apply class with numbers increasing for each next item I'd have but I'm getting stuck when trying to choose proper selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jquery [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) is one of the way

```js
$('.wrapper-button').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings('p.wrapper-text').toggle();

});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper-text {
  background-color: salmon;
}

.wrapper-button {
  background-color: darkred;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='wrapper-button' id="btn-1">
    Click me
  </div>
  <p class='wrapper-text' id="txt-1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>

<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='wrapper-button' id="btn-2">
    Click me
  </div>
  <p class='wrapper-text' id="txt-2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in two ways:

First, use .find() to find children elements:

```
$('.wrapper-button').click(function(){
    $(this).parent(".wrapper").find('.wrapper p').toggle();
});
```

Or, give context to the selector

```
$('.wrapper-button').click(function(){
    $('.wrapper p', $(this).parent(".wrapper")).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're toggling all the `p`s which are siblings of the `.wrapper-button`s. Instead, you need to target only the currently clicked element's sibling:

```js
$('.wrapper-button').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings('p').toggle();
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper-text {
  background-color: salmon;
}

.wrapper-button {
  background-color: darkred;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='wrapper-button' id="btn-1">
    Click me
  </div>
  <p class='wrapper-text' id="txt-1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>

<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='wrapper-button' id="btn-2">
    Click me
  </div>
  <p class='wrapper-text' id="txt-2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `.next()` of `juqery` to toggle the very next element you want. as `p` in your cases

```js
$('.wrapper-button').click(function(){
 $(this).next("p").toggle();
});
```

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.wrapper-text{
  
  background-color:salmon;
}

.wrapper-button{
  background-color:darkred;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='wrapper-button' id="btn-1">
    Click me
  </div>
  <p class='wrapper-text' id="txt-1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>

<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='wrapper-button' id="btn-2">
    Click me
  </div>
  <p class='wrapper-text' id="txt-2">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've to use "this" which refer to the current clicked node, then find the [parent](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) wraaper and finnaly [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) the paragragh and toggle it's display

see below snippet :

```js
$('.wrapper-button').click(function(){
 $(this).parents(".wrapper").find("p").toggle();
});
```

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.wrapper-text{
  
  background-color:salmon;
}

.wrapper-button{
  background-color:darkred;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
<div class='wrapper-button' id="btn-1">
  Click me
</div>
<p class='wrapper-text' id="txt-1">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
</div>

<div class='wrapper'>
<div class='wrapper-button' id="btn-2">
  Click me
</div>
<p class='wrapper-text' id="txt-2">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use "this" instead of class.

```
$('.wrapper-button').click(function(){
    $(this).next("p").toggle();
});

$('.wrapper-button').click(function(){
     $(this).find("p").toggle();
});
```